# Change li a style using javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a menu which i need to change li a style of this:

```
document.getElementById(li).style.background ="red";
```

CSS of this is:

```
.menu, .menu li ul{
list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
width: 191px;
background ="blue"

}

.menu li{
position: relative;
}

.menu li a{
border-radius: 5px;
background: white url(../graphics/glossyback.gif) repeat-x bottom left;
font: 12px Verdana, Helvetica, sans-serif;
color: white;
display: block;
width: auto;
padding: 5px 0;
padding-left: 10px;
text-decoration: none;
}
```

It is changing background but only in .menu li ul.
I want to change background in .menu li a.
Appreciate your help.

Comment: What's your relevant html?

Comment: `.menu .li a` has its own `background: white` which covers over the red of the containing list item.

Comment: Also, you probably want to get elements by **tag name** and not by **id**.

Answer (score 2):

You are missing quotes. `document.getElementById('li');` will return the first element with the id `li`

You can change its background like:

```
document.getElementById('li').style.background ="red";
```

For selecting multiple elements with a class name `li` you can use

```
document.getElementsByClassName('li')
```

For more accurate selections you can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.menu li a')
```

which returns a list of matching nodes on which you can iterate and set the background as follows:

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('.menu li a');
elements.forEach(el => el.style.background = 'red')
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using something like jQuery because it will do a lot of the heavy lifting for you. Also it will make it compatible with other browsers, which you will find overtime is going to be one of the most time consuming things of web development.

But to answer your question to do it in javascript you can do the following:

document.querySelectorAll('#li a').style.background = "red";

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS here `.menu li{` suggests that the `li` is an element and not an id assigned to another element. So you should use

```
var li = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for(var i = 0; li[i]; i++){       
    li[i].style.background = "red";  //works for multiple `<li>` elements on the page
}
```

Or to get specifically the exact results, use:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".menu li ul, .menu li a");  // and the same for loop follows
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/GaurangTandon/r4ysv/2/)